# Integrate Salesforce for multiple clients in a single Webapp to Sync data?

Tags: rest-api, integration, single-sign-on

I am currently doing some research on how I can integrate Salesforce in our webapp and I am having trouble finding the appropriate methods or docs.

My use case:

We have a multi-tenant website where each tenant has their own login, site and data. We want an option where said tenant can 'connect' with salesforce using their salesforce login (SSO likely).

Once connected, we want them to be able to sync the data from our site to their saleforce account (one way from us to salesforce) using the Rest API.

The data here is mostly reports about sessions being done and sales data from our website.

Is this possible in a way where our client doesn't need to set up anything except for using the SSO login. They are very non-technical users so we want the user experience for them to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: In essence, yes its perfectly possible to do that - you would of course have to write code on your side to consume the REST API. Perhaps to get a good answer, you might need to be a little more specific about what you're wanting to integrate to, but for SObjects (basically database tables) you can refer to the REST API docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) decision guide